# Calling external JSON date with nested arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

Been going over lots of examples of JSON with nested arrays but having trouble finding and learning how to apply it to my needs. I have a website that I want to grab username and password info from external JSON file using JQuery.

I built the JSON file with this structure:

```
{"manufacturers": [
{"Acura": {
    "username":"some_username",
    "password":"some_password"
},
"Audi" : {
    "username":"some_username",
    "password":"some_password"
}]
```

I had the idea to grab only the log-in info needed on click with Jquery by using ID of the element clicked to identify which username and password was needed and to append it to a textarea element with ID of "#Audiusername" and "#Audiopassword" such as...

```
$('.accordion > dt > a').click(function(event) {
var clickID = event.target.id;
$("#" + clickID +"username").append(makeUsername);
$("#" + clickID +"password").append(makePassword);
```

I have the JQuery working to insert a value as set string in the append field but I want to pass the needed variables there from the JSON file. I am trying to setup it up this way to make it easier to manage updating the log-in info by keep it separate like this. I am having trouble trying to come up with a JQuery statement tho that can parse the external data.json file on click and assign the username and password to variables for the textarea elements. Any ideas? Help appreciated. New to working with JSON.

Comment: Believe it or not, there is a function `jQuery.getJSON()`. Did you consider using that?

Answer (score 0):

That's a wrong JSON. Should be:

```
{
    "manufacturers": [
        {
            "Acura": {
                "username": "some_username",
                "password": "some_password"
            },
            "Audi": {
                "username": "some_username",
                "password": "some_password"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

And for using it, use `$.getJSON()` from jQuery.

Comment: Ahh... so I had a couple of things off in the JSON. Thanks. I guess I am just stuck at creating the function that I can call with .getJSON() on click that would use the clickID to identify which key and value to access from the nested array.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getLogin() {
$.getJSON('data3.json')
var makeUsername = manufacturers.clickID.username.val();
var makePassword = manufacturers.clickID.password.val();
};
```

thought this combined with my click event

```
  $('.accordion > dt > a').click(function(event) {
    var clickID = event.target.id;
    getLogin();
    $(this).parent().css('transform','scale(1.1,1.1)');
    $(this).parent().next().delay(200).slideDown(600,'linear');
    $("#" + clickID +"username").append(makeUsername);
    $("#" + clickID +"password").append(makePassword);
    $('.downloads').delay(600).slideDown(600);
    return false;
     });
```

would do it but I am having a problem somewhere